# Drawing a second RenderTarget2D to the back buffer overwrites the first one

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

My problem is that I'm trying to get two different RenderTarget2Ds drawn to the screen, but only the last-drawn one is shown. The code is similar to the following, and gets called twice, once by each instance of a class that needs to be drawn with the `Draw` method:

```
public override void Draw()
{
  gfxDevice.SetRenderTarget(myRenderTarget);
  gfxDevice.Clear(Thistle);

  //pseudocode
  foreach (something in a list)
  { spritebatch.begin();
    spritebatch.DrawString(something);
    spritebatch.end();
  }

  //reset to the backbuffer 
  gfxDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
  gfxDevice.Clear(backgroundColor)  //Here is what I thought the offending line was


  //draw the RenderTarget to backbuffer
  spriteBatch.Begin();
  spriteBatch.Draw(myRenderTarget, rect, this.backgroundColor);
  spriteBatch.End();
```

What I thought would be the solution is to stop clearing the `graphicsDevice` each time the `Draw()` method gets called, but if I don't,  everything but the freshly drawn rendertarget gets drawn an ugly purple. Like this: [image]

The purple results from `End()`ing the spritebatch, I think, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270507/changing-rendertarget-results-in-purple-screen)

**What do I need to change in order for both RenderTargets get drawn properly, meaning both widgets get drawn, along with the proper `Color.Thistle` background?**

Ideally, the screen would look like a combination of both: [image: this] and [image: this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that you need to remove the `gfxDevice.Clear(backgroundColor)` call.  If you draw to the backbuffer, and then clear the backbuffer, then obviously anything you drew before clearing isn't going to show up!

You want to clear the backbuffer *before rendering anything*, i.e. at the beginning of the frame.

**EDIT**

After taking a more thorough look at the source code provided, I think I know what's actually going on here--it's one of the tricky things about using render targets.

The weird purple you're seeing is not, in fact, caused by `SpriteBatch.End()`.  That's the color that render targets are automatically cleared to when XNA resets their memory.

When does XNA clear out a render target's memory?  *Whenever that render target is set onto the graphics device as an active target.*  So whenever you call `SetRenderTarget(null)`, XNA is obliterating the backbuffer's memory and resetting it to that lovely purple.

To avoid this, you need to draw *all* of your render targets *before drawing anything to the backbuffer*.  Then, set the backbuffer as your active render target, and draw all of the render targets you updated previously in a single pass.

Comment: That's what my first thought was:  I've tried taking out that line, putting it before any of the `Draw()` calls in the XNA's `Game.Draw()`, and I still only end up with one widget being drawn, along with a purple background on everything but the widget.

Comment: That is to say, if I take out the `gfxDevice.Clear` line, the only thing being drawn is still just the last widget drawn and purple, instead of both widgets and the proper colored background. Take a look: http://i.imgur.com/KgaIl.jpg

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to instantiate the render targets?

Comment: Wonderful! My colleague just came to the same conclusion! We moved the `Spritebatch.Begin/End` into the XNA.Game1.Draw and achieved the same effect. Now, we understand a bit more why that happened thanks to you. Cheers man, you really helped me out.